# Método eficiente para filtrar dados com sequelize

Tags: sequelize-js

Para pegar dados com períodos específicos  do BD com sequelize,  eu uso o Where.

Por exemplo:

```
where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Dec 01 2022"), new Date("Dec 31 2022")],
      },
    },
```

Mas para filtrar esses dados, todos os meses, ou até mesmo todos os dias do mês, ficaria um código muito grande.
Não me leve a mau, não estou reclamando de ter que fazer todos os dias, só queria saber se existe um método mais eficiente.

Alguém sabe me dizer se existe um método mais eficiente, ou mais correto de se fazer esse filtro?

Por exemplo, para filtrar os meu dados no front, eu estou fazendo uma rota para cada mês do ano.(Utilizando o express).

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/2021", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/2022", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/janeiro", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/fevereiro", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/marco", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/maio", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

Etc...

Outro exemplo é quando preciso filtrar os dados para apresentar em um gráfico:

```
  ////////////////////////////////////////janeiro
  var amountPJ = await Payment.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Jan 01 2022"), new Date("Jan 31 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalPaymentsJ = amountPJ['sum(`valor`)']

  var amountRJ = await Receipt.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Jan 01 2022"), new Date("Jan 31 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalReceiptsJ = amountRJ['sum(`valor`)']

  var somaJ = parseInt(-totalPaymentsJ) + parseInt(totalReceiptsJ);

  //////////////////////////////fevereiro
  var amountPF = await Payment.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Feb 01 2022"), new Date("Feb 28 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalPaymentsF = amountPF['sum(`valor`)']

  var amountRF = await Receipt.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Feb 01 2022"), new Date("Feb 28 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalReceiptsF = amountRF['sum(`valor`)']

  var somaF = parseInt(-totalPaymentsF) + parseInt(totalReceiptsF);

  ///////////////////////////////////marco
  var amountPMar = await Payment.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Mar 01 2022"), new Date("Mar 31 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalPaymentsMar = amountPMar['sum(`valor`)']

  var amountRMar = await Receipt.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Mar 01 2022"), new Date("Mar 31 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalReceiptsMar = amountRMar['sum(`valor`)']

  var somaMar = parseInt(-totalPaymentsMar) + parseInt(totalReceiptsMar);
  ///////////////////////////////////abril
  var amountPAp = await Payment.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Apr 01 2022"), new Date("Apr 30 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalPaymentsAp = amountPAp['sum(`valor`)']

  var amountRAp = await Receipt.findOne({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
    where: {
      data: {
        [Op.between]: [new Date("Apr 01 2022"), new Date("Apr 30 2022")],
      },
    },
    raw: true
  });
  var totalReceiptsAp = amountRAp['sum(`valor`)']

  var somaAp = parseInt(-totalPaymentsAp) + parseInt(totalReceiptsAp);
```

Este é um exemplo se eu for mostra-los separados por mês, mas precisando filtrar por todos os dias do mês, ou semanalmente, vai ficar um código bastante extenso, com muitas variáveis.

Se poder me informar se é esse método que devo usar, o se esta incorreto, eu agradeceria.

PS:Esses valores eu estou pegando do banco de Dados, Mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No caso das rotas, você poderia passar os valores por parâmetro.

Ao invés de

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/2021", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

Você poderia usar algo como:

```
router.get("/admin/payments/index/{year}/{month}", adminAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
```

E pegar os valores de req.params.year e req.params.month, assim você teria apenas uma rota.

Sobre as queries em si, você parece estar repetindo bastante código. Uma regra interessante pra se ter em mente é: assim que você ver código repetido, tente transformar ele numa função parametrizada.

Exemplo de como poderia ficar esse bloco de código que você incluiu:

```
const getAmountMonth = async (table, month, year) => {
    const dt1 = new Date(year, month-1, 1);
    const dt2 = new Date(year, month, 0);

    const row = await table.findOne({
        attributes: [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("valor"))],
        where: {
            data: {
                [Op.between]: [dt1, dt2],
            },
        },
        raw: true
    });
    return row['sum(`valor`)'];
};

const getTotalMonth = async (month, year) => {
    const payments = await getAmountMonth(Payment, month, year);
    const receipts = await getAmountMonth(Receipt, month, year);
    return  parseInt(-payments) + parseInt(receipts);
};


var somaJ = await getTotalMonth(1,2022);
var somaF = await getTotalMonth(2,2022);
var somaM = await getTotalMonth(3,2022);
var somaAp = await getTotalMonth(4,2022);
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, sua resposta foi de grande ajuda!!!